# Adding a UILabel or NSString to UIalertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I would like to add a bunch of UILabels or NSStrings to the UIALertView since I have run out of space on my display.

```
UIAlertView *alertDialog;
alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
               initWithTitle:@"random" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];


//firstString=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(12.0, 70.0, 260.0, 25.0)];

[alertDialog addSubview:firstString];
[alertDialog show];
[alertDialog release];
```

Comment: This isn't really a good use of a UIAlertView. Have you considered making your interface a scroll view to get more space?

Comment: How isn't it working?  Can you show the error from gdb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that this is a bad idea.  In earlier version or iOS there were tricks using undocumented behavior, Apple made changes to the underlaying code and it all broke badly.  Just create a UIView the way you like.  If you want to dim the rest of the screen just place a semi-transparenr view over the screen and under your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a alternative implementation of an alert view. One, that is **not** a subclass of UIAlertView — so it is absolutely independent to any changes Apple may release. And you have the possibility to add any subview as a clean property.

[TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) is such an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use uitextfield to do so ,

simply change textcolor to while , and change background color to clearColor